# Is it a bug that I am not able to Vote for Re-Open twice?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

Please consider this situation:

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1172470/what-is-quantum-computing-closed

This question got closed, reopened (I voted for this), closed. I want to reopen this question but it says:

> You have already (or previously) voted to reopen this question
>   (click on this box to dismiss)

Why can't I reopen it again?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can only vote to close or reopen the same question once total. So you voted to reopen once, it closed again and you've used your one vote for that question. So this isn't a bug but by design. Once upon a time you could repeatedly vote but this tended to lead to edit wars with the same people. This way requires more people to get involved to change the outcome, which is probably a good thing.

Comment: Thats wrong , Because as i am owner i can vote for it .. because if i am not agree for closing .. So i can reopen any time or some time other users think , they placed wrong  vote and they can change it again

Comment: @Krish: As the owner you shouldn't have *any* reopen votes, Imho. Of course you want the question open, else you wouldn't have posted it in the first place. Opening/closing is about what the other users think of your question.

Comment: @sth : But i am having option to Vote for Reopen or Close my question myself .. That how its works

Answer (score 1):

The idea of this was to stop the many close/reopen wars we once had. In my opinion it did not address the true problem, but it seems to have helped a bit.

Status: By design.