# Policy on closing quality questions or questions which have been reviewed previously

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, policy

This is a two part question.

1. Are we keeping track of repeated close votes by the same person?

Here are bunch of reviews from the last couple days:

- [What is the best practice for multiple Include method calls in Entity Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/2613330)
- [How to install Clang from the binary distribution?](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/2607895)
- [What are the main differences between Scala and Frege (in programming paradigms)?](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/2602340)
- [Is a program F# any more efficient (execution-wise) than C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/2613792)

At the time of writing, all of these already have pending close votes again. I feel like I'm constantly reviewing the same questions over and over. I suspect that some people repeatedly cast close votes until they get their way. Which generates a lot of unnecessary work for the reviewers.

I think if a question is reviewed and it was decided to leave it open, that question should be protected from subsequent close-votes by the same person - or maybe even close-votes by everybody for a limited period of time (couple of days maybe).

2. Should we even allow Off-topic, Unclear, Too Broad, Opinion-Based close-votes on quality questions? (excluding Duplicates)

Again if you look at the examples, they all have multiple up-votes. Some have been favorited multiple times. Or they have accepted answers which have been upvoted multiple times. To me these are clear indicators that the StackOverflow community thinks that these are relevant questions which have merit. Reviewing close votes on such questions feels like a waste of time.

Comment: *"I suspect that some people repeatedly cast close votes until they get their way."* ... how would that be possible?

Comment: @Bart I meant, they close-vote again after it was rejected the first time. That's possible, no?

Comment: Unless I'm very much mistaken or misunderstanding, that's not possible. And keep in mind that popularity of a question does not necessarily mean it's a good fit for the site.

Comment: @Bart well, that would rule out my suspicion. Frankly, I never tried it.

Comment: It used to be possible to cast another close vote after a question was reopened. It's not anymore. I don't know that it was ever possible if your close vote had just expired/been removed because of Keep Open reviews.

Comment: @Wooble ,Bart yeah you're both right. I found on old question which confirms that [multiple close votes by the same person are not allowed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8907/is-it-a-bug-that-i-am-not-able-to-vote-for-re-open-twice).

Comment: Popularity of a question usually indicates it is less of a fit.

Comment: @user7116 Are you saying "popular" questions are less likely to be on-topic?